# StackO: A Windows Phone 7 StackExchange App

Tags: app, windows-phone

### EDIT

**STACKO is now available for download from the Marketplace.

For features/suggestions please visit http://stacko.uservoice.com/**

StackO is a StackExchange browser allowing you to search the whole range of StackExchange family of sites including StackOverflow, ServerFault, SuperUser, Mathematics, Gaming and many more.

[image: stacko thumb site selector]
[image: stacko site browser]
[image: stacko questions browser]
[image: stacko question item]
[image: stacko users browser]
[image: stacko user item]

StackO allows you to "Watch" the questions of your choice to keep up-to-date with the status of a question. Giving you direct access to the questions that interest you most.

### **Support/Suggestions**

All suggestions will be gratefully received (good and bad).

Unfortunately I'm unable to post images here due to a lack of reputation points (oddly). If you want to see more please visit my blog http://www.ryantomlinson.com/

### How Much Is It?

It's 100% absolutely and completely **FREE** and always will be!

### Platform

Currently only available for Windows Phone 7

### Support/Feedback

Please leave feedback here. It will be very gratefully received. Ideas and suggestions will be best voiced at http://stacko.uservoice.com/

Comment: If you prepare slightly smaller images, I'll insert them in your question. Also, what's that thing with truncated titles in your screenshots?

Comment: Thing with truncated titles in my screenshots? Can you elaborate? There isn't anything truncated in the screenshots. Windows Phone 7 displays the titles like this by default as a part of their UX.

Comment: Hi there! Looks great - unfortunately I can't find the app in the Markedplace? I'm using a UK Windows Live Id... Maybe that's why?

Comment: @kennethkryger - StackO is still being tested by MS and is awaiting confirmation before it is on the marketplace. I will update as soon as it becomes available and supply a zune link for you.

Comment: @Ryan You mean, "question answ" and "Stack Overflo" are limitations of WP7? That's the hell of a platform :)  But overall, application looks nice.

Comment: @Nikita. No they are not "limitations" rather than design decisions that fit with the overall "Metro" design guidelines. If you wish to know more you can read up about the justification here -> http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/03/18/windows-phone-7-series-ui-design-amp-interaction-guide.aspx

Comment: Hello, want to try your app, but I cant find it in marketplace. I am from Czech republic. Is your app submitted world-wide?